# Laravel return 302 in some machine - browser

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I have a stranger behavior in my application, if open this url

```
http://example.com/Pd/Country/1
```

In some machines and browser, I got the expected result and response code is `200` where other machines return `302`

In my `routes`

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'Pd'), function() {
   Route::get('Country/{id}','CountryController@getAll');
});
```

**Updates**
I found out the problem is session not persisted in some machine and browser , I have got some suggestions to add `Session::save();` after `Session::push('keyvalue',$keyvalue );`but still not working

Comment: check the server log

Comment: @ImtiazPabel thanks for suggestion , I found out the problem is session not persisted in some machine and browser  , I have got some suggestions to add `Session::save();`  after `Session::push('keyvalue',$keyvalue );` but is not working

Comment: It might help if you added the code for `CountryController@getAll` so we can see what is happening beyond the route.

Comment: @JamesO'Neill The issue is now on **session** , in  AuthController I set session as  `Session::push('keyvalue',$keyvalue ); ` and  if I try to get the value as `$keyvalue   = Session::get('keyvalue');` it gives **null**

Comment: If `'keyvalue'` is meant to be saving the value of the `id` route parameter then you should probably be using `Session::put()` rather than `Session::push()`.

Comment: @JamesO'Neill Thanks for suggestions , were really helpful to find the solution I just posted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The Real Problem**

The url were different i.e: Sessions set on `example.com` and the next request done on `http://www.example.com/`on which the sessions were not set  .

**The Solution**

I had to change my `.htaccess` file so that whether user type `www.example.com` , `example.com` or `http://example.com/` will be changed to `http://www.example.com/`

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```